# java unit test with selenium getting nullpointer exception for @inject function

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am trying to unit test Sign On method in selenium. My Sign On method is injecting other pages which is taking webdriver in turn.

**SignOn.java**

```
import ...

@PageObject
public class SignOn {

@Inject 
BasePage basepage

public void signOn(driver,user,password){
    basepage.clickhamburgermenu() #This line is not instantiated when 
    unit testing but works fine when just running this file.
```

}

**BasePage.java**

```
import ...

public class BasePage {

Map<String, String> data;
WebDriver driver;


@Inject
public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void clickHamburgerMenu() {
    if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(hamburgerMenu)).size() > 0)
    {
        WebElement burgerMenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(hamburgerMenu));
        if(burgerMenu.isDisplayed()){burgerMenu.click();}
    }
}
```

**SignOntest.java**

```
import ...

public class signOnTest{

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
signOn = new SignOn();
}

@Test
public void testSignOn() {
    webDriver.get("www.facebook.com");
    SignOn.SignOn(webDriver,"user","password");
    } 

}
```

Here, I wanna unit test sign-on method but it fails on basepage initiation. I am not that pro in dependency injection. Anything helps.

Comment: Where is the NPE occuring? Can you paste the text of the error?

Comment: @C.Peck java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SignOn.SignOn(SignOn.java) 
Error is coming from this line     basepage.clickhamburgermenu() in BasePage.java

Also, this works when running signOn feature. It's just that it is somehow not instantiated when unit testing.